# Как добавить пробел в строку PHP?

Tags: php, строки

Делаю фильтр для сайта.
Пользователь вводит цену, к примеру, 25000 руб.
Как мне из "25000" сделать "25 000" руб.?

Comment: В документации есть функции для этого<br>
http://ru2.php.net/number_format<br>
http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пользоваться функцией number_format:

```
echo "$ ".number_format($value, 2);
```

или sprintf:

```
echo sprintf('%0.2f', $value);
```